# how to create Half Screen Camera View in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to display live camera view in Half of the Screen and the remaining half screen needs to insert some control in Xamarin Forms. for camera purpose, I am using "Plugin.Media;" but plugin opens new camera window. the same page should display on iOS and Android. please suggest me how can I develop/design this page.
OR How to create any custom renderer form this view.

[image: Wireframe]

Answer (score 4):

You will need a Custom View Renderer to achieve it.
The Xamarin Forms Offical documentation has an example of it, you can check here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

About the rest of the controls in the design, you can do it using Xamarin Forms Controls (Buttons, Images, etc)

Comment: Thanks. That minis I need to create the only camera View renderer rather than whole page renderer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a Custom Renderer.

Create your basic ContentPage or BasePage CameraView.xaml in your PCL.

In your Android Project you need to create the Camera Ui like here

https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments/blob/master/Moments%20-%20CSharp/Moments.Droid/Resources/layout/CameraLayout.axml

now just write the Renderer like here:

https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments/blob/master/Moments%20-%20XAML/Moments.Droid/Pages/CameraPage.cs

The same steps  are also for iOS just use https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments for learning.